# Using LINQ to Update A Property in a List of Entities

Tags: linq

Say I have an entity that looks something like this simple example:

```
MyEntity 
{
   int property1;
   int property2;
   int property3;
}
```

Now assume I have an `IEnumerable` list of these entites. Is there a LINQ query I can execute that would set the value of `property1` to 100 for each entity in the list? I know I can do this via a foreach, but was wondering if LINQ could do this more elegantly.

Comment: LINQ is for querying (lin-Q), not modifying.

Comment: @GertArnold - Too bad I cannot downvote comments. You are wrong.

Comment: I don't mind to be wrong, but I like to know why.

Comment: Well, no response to that. Some answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46522707/861716), use LINQ the way it is not designed for, i.e. with side effects. They rely on code that forces execution, which is easily forgotten, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785146/861716) of which the writer is even aware of the right paradigm. Others, like the accepted one, use LINQ for querying data and subsequent code to modify the data. That is the right way.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Like this:

```
var result = GetMyIEnumerable()
                .ToList();
result.ForEach(x => x.property1 = 100);
```

Comment: absolutely fantastic! so subtle, but powerful

Comment: I realize this is a super old thread, but I stumbled upon this looking for a solution like...
var Result = Items.SetProperty(x => x.property1 = 1);
Does this exist?

Comment: I know this is super old thread, but given the information provided in the question this code would be reduced to the ForEach() line on it's own, there is no need for ToList().

Answer (score 25):

Here are two solutions that I found that worked for me.

```
result = result.Where(x => (x.property1 = 100) == 100).ToList();
```

or

```
result = result.Select(c => { c.property1 = 100; return c; }).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this "Select" version better than ForEach because ForEach doesn't work on ICollection<T> and you can't do myicollection.ToList().ForEach in a "one-liner" because ForEach is void. The "Where" version though is black magic that you should be exiled for uncovering. ;)

Comment: How can you do this in SQL syntax?

Answer (score 18):

To Darin's point, LINQ is built for querying.  I've gotten into the mindset when working with LINQ that objects being queried should be treated as immutable.  However, the *Select* operator is also great for transformations.

So, you could solve your problem by transforming from one set to another as follows:

```
var result = myEntityCollection.Select(e => {
   var ret = e;
   e.property1 = 100;
   return e; });
```

The items in the original collection are untouched, but the items in result will now all have property1 set to 100.

Comment: `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`

Comment: The items in the original collection are *not* untouched. They will be modified when the statement you show is actually executed (which it isn't, presently).

Answer (score 5):

If you have 100 properties maybe reflection would be most elegant. LINQ's for querying not updating.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Darrelk** and **mkedobbs**, **VB.NET Code**:

```
object.list =
    object.list.Select(Function(x)
                           x.property = If(x.property.Length > 3, x.property.Substring(0, 3), x.property)
                           Return x
                       End Function).ToList()
```