# How to update value in a List using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, c#-4.0

I have a list which I want to update using LINQ.

```
class Student
{
    private string name;
    private int marks;
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Marks { get; set; }
    public Student(string name, int marks)
    {
        Name = name;
        Marks = marks;
    }
}

List<Student> myList = new List<Student>();
myList.Add(new Student("John", 10));
myList.Add(new Student("Tom", 20));
```

Now I want to update the list using LINQ such that only marks of John gets updated. I am using the following syntax:

```
myList.Where(w => w.Name == "Tom").Select(w=> { w.Marks = 35; return w});
```

But this doesnt update data in myList. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: `LINQ` is used for querying data not updating. Better to do it using a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I tried foreach(item in myList.where(w => w.Name == "Tom")) { item.Marks = 35; } but get an error - cannot modify members of 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: Your code as posted does not compile - missing parens, mismatched data types, inconsistent capitalization, hiding of fields in constructor, etc.  If you post something that is closer to your original code and _actually compiles_ then the problem may be apparent.  As it stands a simple `foreach` after your query should work.

Comment: The code you claim generates the 'cannot modify members of 'item'' does not.  It would generate this if `Student` was a `struct` rather than a `class`.  The sample code you provide doesn't compile.  Can you provide the *actual* code you're using?

Answer (score 46):

LINQ is for querying, not for updating the data. Use LINQ to get the items that you want to modify, and then modify them in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ( var tom in myList.Where(w => w.Name == "Tom")) {
    tom.Marks = 35;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/XguO3N)

Comment: This gives an  error - cannot modify members of 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: IEnumerable cannot be modify

Comment: This shouldn't give error. It is perfectly fine code and does the modification as well, not really sure about the downvote.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad There is nothing in this code that would try modifying `IEnumerable` Modifying members of `IEnumerable`, on the other hand, is a 100% fair game.

Comment: @user3625024 You shouldn't get any errors, provided that your `Student` class is the same as is shown in your question. I added the demo to show how this works.

Answer (score 22):

Try:

```
myList .Where(w=> w.Name  == "dTomi").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Marks  = 35);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain anything, while OP is asking what they're doing wrong. Code-only answers are far more valuable when they also contain an explanation.

Answer (score 12):

`Select()`, like any other LINQ method, doesn't change a source collection, instead, it return a new collection.

So you should either assign that new collection to `myList`:

```
myList = myList.Where(w => w.Name == "Tom").Select(w => { w.Marks = 35; return w}).ToList();
```

or assign `Marks` property in a separate foreach loop

```
myList.Where(w => w.Name == "Tom").ToList().ForEach(w => w.Marks = 35);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden though its an old post, but you mean to say readers in future wont be able to read the question to understand why this code suggestion is here? Because I read all answers and understood all of them, despite being few of them are without explanation.

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out, LINQ is for querying data, it is not for doing updates.

You should iterate your list, and modify your values like:

```
foreach (var student in myList)
{
    if (student.Name == "Tom")
    {
        student.Marks = 35;
    }
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var student in myList.Where(r => r.Name == "Tom"))
{
    student.Marks = 35;
}
```

Whatever you think better conveys the intent use that.

---

but here is an interesting thing:

If you have a statement like:

```
myList.Where(w => w.Name == "Tom").Select(w => w.Marks = 35).ToList();
```

Without assigning the result back to `myList` the above query will modify the value in the original list. **Remember, it is a side effect and it is not the *proper* way to update**. This is modification can be explained by reference parameter being passed to a method and getting modified there. **But Importantly, this should always be avoided**. It is a bad practice and could lead to really confusing code. Use LINQ for querying only.

Comment: +1 This points out an important point that was driving me nuts since many posts supply your anti-pattern as the answer and I was wondering if I understood the Q in LINQ properly. Thanks :-)

Comment: See this post for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776387/using-linq-to-update-a-property-in-a-list-of-entities

Answer (score 3):

Above can be achieved by just assign the value back to the collection

```
myList = myList
        .Where(w => w.Name == "Tom")
        .Select(w=> { w.Marks = 35; return w})
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Objects are stored by reference in the list so you can recover object via linq and then edit, it will be reflect the changes on the list.

Example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Entity> testList = new List<Entity>()
            {
                new Entity() {Id = 1, Text = "Text"},
                new Entity() {Id = 2, Text = "Text2"}
            };

            Console.WriteLine($"First text value:{testList[1].Text}");

            Entity entityToEdit = testList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 2);
            if (entityToEdit != null)
                entityToEdit.Text = "Hello You!!";

            Console.WriteLine($"Edited text value:{testList[1].Text}");
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

 internal class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Testing the app you will get the follow result:

> First text value:Text2
>
> Edited text value:Hello You!!

Comment: The other answers already made this point. I don't think your answer adds much to this.

Answer (score 0):

how about old good `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
if (myList[i].Name  == "Tom")
{
    myList[i].Marks = 35;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well @dasblinkenlight code should work but you can also try something like this

```
 var query = from x in list
             where x.Name = yourcondition
             select new { x };
foreach(var item in query)
   item.x.FieldToUpdate = SetValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of clunky, but works, and doesn't depend on being passed a reference.  It creates a new list based on the old.

```
var myList=myList.Select(l=>new Student { 
   l.Name,
   Marks=l.Name=="Tom"?35:l.Marks}).ToList();
```

Or more silly:

```
var myList=myList.Where(l=>l.Name!="Tom").Union(
  myList.Where(l=>l.Name=="Tom").Select(l=>new Student { 
   l.Name,
   Marks=35})).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

List can be updated with linq as sample code below, to avoid iteration :

```
        if (resultQuiz.ANSWER_Q != null) {
            questionsvm.Where(x => x.QUESTION_ID == resultQuiz.QUESTION_ID).FirstOrDefault().ANSWER_Q = resultQuiz.ANSWER_Q;

            questionsvm.Where(x => x.QUESTION_ID == resultQuiz.QUESTION_ID).FirstOrDefault().ISCORRECT =
                questionsvm.Where(x => x.QUESTION_ID == resultQuiz.QUESTION_ID).FirstOrDefault().ANSWER_TEXT.ToLower() == resultQuiz.ANSWER_Q.ToLower();             
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where clause will get the item in the list object which has the "Marks" object for you to assign the new value.

```
myList.Where(w => w.Name == "Tom").FirstOrDefault().Marks = 35;
```