# Entity Framework equivalent of SQL relative update

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

If I want to increase the value in a table column with SQL I can do it as follows:

```
UPDATE mytable m SET m.mycolumn = m.mycolumn + 1;
```

This is great because it doesn't rely on being executed in any order and uses an absolute minimum of locking.

How can this be done using C# and Entity Framework, with the same (or as close as possible) minimal overhead?

Comment: In short, you can't. You can execute a sql statement through the ado.net properties available on the DbContext instance. You could also created a stored procedure if this is a specific action that occurs where the stored proc does this. That is the closest you will get to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't. You can execute a sql statement through the ado.net properties available on the [DbContext.Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). You could also created a stored procedure if this is a specific action that occurs where the stored proc does this. That is the closest you will get to this.

This answer assumes you already know how to retrieve all the records, iterate over them to change the value of the property, and then persist the changes using `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext` and that this is not what you are looking for as it generates 1 update statement per record.

Comment: That is my current thinking also.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, it's not possible in Pure EF.
As always you're free to create your pure SQL statements and run them through your context.
The closest thing to your question is to use Entity Framework Extensions. The have an UpdateFromQuery method: https://entityframework-extensions.net/update-from-query
This would look like this:

```
context.mytable.UpdateFromQuery(x => new mytable() {mycolumn = x.mycolumn + 1});
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. Will be interesting to see what query output that executes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

```cs
context.mytable
  .Set(x => x.mycolumn, x => x.mycolumn + 1)
  .Update();
```

Library has it's own LINQ Translator which eliminates a lot of EF Core limitations.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbContext.Entity.ForEach(x -> x.property = value);
```

or

```
dbContext.Entity.Select(x -> {x.property =100; return c;}).ToList();
```

See [Using LINQ to Update A Property in a List of Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776387/using-linq-to-update-a-property-in-a-list-of-entities)

Comment: This is no the same, the DbContext instance will issue a single update statement (as a batch) for each record once SaveChanges has been called.

Comment: In c# we use `=>`